# Custom Endpoint Created, but I need to target a dynamic page that doesn't exist

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a Code Snippet that's creating a custom tab through the WooCommerce Menu called 'Device Profile':

```
function AddCustomTabEndpoint() {
  add_rewrite_endpoint('Device-Profile', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action('init','AddCustomTabEndpoint' );

function CustomTabQueryVars( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = 'Device-Profile';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars','CustomTabQueryVars', 0 );

function AddCustomTabMyAccount( $items ) {
  $items['Device-Profile'] = 'My Custom Tab';
  return $items;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items','AddCustomTabMyAccount');

function MyCustomTabContent() {
  echo "<h3>Device-Profile</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>";
}
add_action('woocommerce_account_Device-Profile_endpoint','MyCustomTabContent');
```

..but now there is a brick wall. I can't point the menu link to a specific page because it doesn't exist. The page is created after a user submits a form which would look something like https://www.123.com/page_is_built/12345.

This URL doesn't lead anywhere, but as a reference, "page_is_built" would define the subdirectory and "12345" would be the endpoint that needs to be targeted. Again, this doesn't exist until the user submits a form on the website. I also can't predict what the endpoint URL will be... So how would I target the endpoint?

Comment: What do you mean by this `I can't point the menu link to a specific page because it doesn't exist`  What are you asking for.  Do you want to modify the menu so a link shows up or do you want an actual endpoint someone could go to that you run some code on?

Comment: If you want to modify the navigation menu then you will want to look into Menu Walkers.  There are some tutorials and such on line.  But it will let you go through the Menu tree and modify things.